# jQuery Autocomplete loosing focus on selecting value

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, lost-focus

I am using the jQuery autocomplete and not UI autocomplete. with option multi = true. However when I select the first option with enter key, the focus is lot from the input control. Even the demo page (http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/ [try typing in Multiple Cities (local)]) has a lost focus. Any help to keep the focus in same control to allow inputting more values.

Comment: for me it has kept focus. what browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May seem out of context, but believe me, this is what you really need.

---

Jörn Zaefferer's jQuery AutoComplete was a wonderful plugin for autocomplete([Read this](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)).
But its now deprecated and so, it would be very hard to maintain that for any project for the latest versions of jQuery.

Here is what Jörn Zaefferer has to say

> **Note (2010-06-23): This plugin is
>   deprecated and not developed anymore.
>   Its successor is part of [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/),
>   and [this migration guide](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide) explains how
>   to get from this plugin to the new
>   one**. This page will remain as it is
>   for reference, but won’t be updated
>   anymore.

So its better to switch to [jQUery UI - AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Comment: Thanks. Migrated my code to jQuery-ui-autocomplete and it is much more powerful that autocomplete.